# Jenkins webhook and no such DSL method error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

### My environment

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Jenkins deploy within K3s, using `bitnami/jenkins` helm chart.

  - Jenkins version: 2.387.3
- I use only one jenkins node.

### Webhook

I created a pipeline job like this and the system log record webhook received already, but the job doesn't trigger. I don't know if I miss any step here ?

[image: Job configuration]

[image: Webhook received]

### No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps

I have to manually trigger the job to test, cause the webhook doesn't trigger it. I know that's a high chance that

- I missed install `Pipeline` plugin and all of its dependencies. But I installed it and checked with its dependencies list [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator/dependencies/).
- There might be some typo in the `Jenkinsfile`. But since I got that error, I tried with barely just hello world template like this, but the error still occur.
  [image: Simple jenkinsfile template]
  [image: Original jenkinsfile template error]
- There might be some weird character prior to `pipeline` definition, so for safety, I hand type the whole file, but nothing changed.
- I tried if I don't use `Pipeline script from SCM`, but use the exact same template with native `Pipeline script` template, it success, regardless `Pipeline` plugin enable or not
  [image: Assumption]

I don't know if I miss anything here... if we need other information to troubleshoot this, I'll update them.

Comment: At this point I'm  beginning to wonder if it is a problem with your Jenkins instance itself (or the pipeline as code plugin). Go into your installed plugins page and look for a plugin called `pipeline`. Uninstall and reinstall. Maybe that will do something?

Comment: For quick update, I just try to uninstall and reinstall it, nothing changed so far :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole week struggling with documents, it turns out that we shouldn't create `Jenkinsfile` within windows environment as they automatically append some short of character at the beggining of the file no matter we hand type or copy paste the content.

When I create it in wsl, everything works fine.